# Abby, Bob, Chris, and Dan have 5 vehicles to choose from how many ways can this be done?

Tags: combinatorics

Abby, Bob, Chris, and Dan have 5 types vehicles to choose from a red car, red truck, green jeep, brown suv, and grey convertible.  More than one person can have the same type of vehicle.  If Abby and Bob cannot have the same color of vehicle how many ways are there to distribute the vehicles among the four people?

I was thinking Abby has 5 choices.  Bob then has 3 choices because Abby might pick a red vehicle.  Chris and Dan would each have 5 choices because it does not matter what color they have for a total of 5*3*5*5 = 375 ways. Do I need multiple cases due to the fact Abby might not pick a red vehicle or how could I solve this?

Comment: Yes, you need the multiple cases, and sum them up in the end... AlexR showed this correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chris and Dan are not important, so the give a factor of $5\cdot 5$. Now for Abby + Bob there are
$3_\text{not red} \cdot 4_\text{other colors} + 2_\text{red} \cdot 3_\text{not red} = 18$
Possibilities, so the total is
$$5\cdot5\cdot 18 = 450$$